# Calculate between 2 rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

Wonder if someone could help?
I have an issue where i need to calculate the difference between row 1 and row 2 and then enter this into another column

The, i need to take the value in the column and then calculate against row 3 and then enter that value into another row in the new column.

That value is then used to calculate row 4 and so on

Not sure if its possible to do so any help would be appreciated

Have tried lead/lag, dense rank

The below is the table with its raw data

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Amt Date
10000   142211  1   -64.05  2005-07-19
10000   142211  2   64.05   2005-07-01
10000   142211  3   -74.91  2005-08-17
10000   142211  4   74.91   2005-08-01
10000   142211  5   -74.91  2005-09-19
10000   142211  6   74.91   2005-09-01
10000   142211  7   0.00    2005-01-01
10000   142211  8   74.91   2005-10-01
10000   142211  9   -74.91  2005-10-19
10000   142211  10  74.91   2005-11-01
```

The difference between 1 and 2 would go into a new column

Comment: Post the expected result next to sample data.

Comment: LAG should do your job.  How have you used it?

Comment: How do you order these records: by `Date`?

Comment: Put your attempt in your question, @SteveWWH , not the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You Just need `LAG` function. Try Like:

```
SELECT *, Amt - LAG(Amt, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY UpdatedDate ASC)
FROM dbo.crm_Transactions
WHERE TenancyRef = '142211'
ORDER BY TenancyRef
    ,TransNo ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for the above, @gordon yes your right we need a running balance but that didnt quite get what we need. @ apomene, almost there as well. THe end result looks like the below Trans-Amt TransNo TransDate 
-64.05 1 2005-07-19 -64.05
64.05 2 2005-07-01 0.00
-74.91 3 2005-08-17 -74.91
74.91 4 2005-08-01 0.00
-74.91 5 2005-09-19 -74.91
74.91 6 2005-09-01 0.00
0.00 7 2005-01-01 0.00
74.91 8 2005-10-01 74.91
-74.91 9 2005-10-19 0.00
74.91 10 2005-11-01 74.91
-74.91 11 2005-11-17 0.00

Answer (score 0):

You are describing what sounds like a cumulative function.  However, I don't see that a difference is useful.  I think a cumulative sum is useful . . . and you are confused by the negative values in the data.

So, this may be what you actually want:

```
select t.*,
       sum(amount) over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3) as running_amount
from t;
```